# How to convert System.Exception into FaultException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have the following method called asynchronously. I want to know how can I convert the `System Exception` (that I might encounter during SQL operations) into a `FaultException`.

Here is the method:

```
public List<Product> GetProductDetails(int productKey)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_ProductDetails", con);
            ........
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ......
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        //How can I convert this Exception ex into FaultException and then throw to client?
        //throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText()), new FaultCode());

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just catch a `FaultException`?

Comment: Probably this link may be helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732013(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097839/how-to-handle-wcf-fault-exception why not use the anwser from here? Passing the type of the exception to the fault exception

Comment: @Steve what would be the format of catching and then throwing `FaultException`? I want to show the `FaultException.Reason` on a MessageBox on the client side code. Can you post answer?

Comment: @HumaAli see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can catch multiple exceptions (and in fact is good practice to do so if a given exception is reasonably likely to occur), then do something with each.

For example:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_ProductDetails", con);
        .....
    }
}
catch(FaultException faultEx)
{
    // code to send to client
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    // code to do something else
}
```

Comment: the code inside `try` shouldn't thow `FaultException`.

Comment: @HumaAli that depends entirely on where and how you're using the method, is it in a controller, model, somewhere else? I'm just answering the question given.

Comment: @Steve I just want to know how to send FaultException message after catching it

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I removed code from the original example for brevity. His code could well throw that exception.

Comment: @HumaAli you should probably edit your question to say that, currently you're just asking how to get the `FaultException`.

Comment: If you want the `FaultException` to be thrown but other exceptions to be caught then `throw;` in the catch-block for `FaultException`. If you aren't reasonably expecting (or able to usefully cope with) any other exception then just don't have the `try` at all.

Comment: This appears to be missing the point of the question: how to make a FaultException out of an Exception? The question is about converting or wrapping a .NET native exception as SQL throws to a WCF / SOAP exception instance FaultException.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Throwing a new exception instance is bad practice because you will lose the entire stack track up to that point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999298/difference-between-throw-and-throw-new-exception

Comment: @Markus this didn't wrap the exception, just the message, so it is indeed lost. Of course, sometimes one wants that *precisely* to lose the stack trace. In this case though it's a different `FaultException` to the one originally thrown, so there's not much point.

Comment: well I thought it's the error message OP is concerned about. I know about stack traces being lost and etc.